# Python: random choice of key from library for flashcard game

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I'm fairly new to python and programming in general, and am trying to create some simple programs. 
I have decided to build a small flashcard program to aid in my study of русский, and have used a dictionary with english definitions as the key, and the русский equivalent as the value. The program runs but I am struggling to figure how I can randomise the word that gets called. I have tried random.choice(vocabulary) but with little success. I have also tried to turn the dictionary key/value pairs into lists but then struggle to call them using the format I have so far used.

Is there a way to randomise the key that gets called using a variation on this script? Further, would a different object type be more useful for such a program? Thanks

```
import random

vocabulary = {
    "to study (imperfective)": "изучать",
     "to begin (imperfective)": "начинать",
     "to begin (perfective)": "начать"
}

n = 0
while n < 1:
for english, russian in vocabulary.items():
    print("Translate:\n" + english + "\n")
    answer = input("Answer:\n" )
    if answer == russian:
        print("Correct!\n")
    else:
        print("Incorrect! Correct answer: \n" + russian + "\n")
```

Comment: [random.choice(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) comes into mind ....

Comment: @PatrickArtner, the answer is literally in the first three words :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) can:

> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence *seq*.

The only problem is that you don't have a sequence here, you have a dictionary.

But a dictionary is an iterable of its keys, so you can directly construct a tuple (or list, or most other kinds of sequences) of its keys:

```
english = random.choice(tuple(vocabulary))
russian = vocabulary[english]
```

Or, since its items view is an iterable of key-value pairs:

```
english, russian = random.choice(tuple(vocabulary.items())
```

For a huge dictionary, this is a bit wasteful, because it copies the keys or items into a tuple just to pick one. But when you're talking about only 3 keys, or even 50000, that isn't going to be a problem, so keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `random` module's `choice` function:

```
from random import choice
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
random_element = choice(numbers)
```

You can call this on a dictionary's `.keys()` to get a random key in python2, or as abarnert says, change your items to a `tuple` (or the keys to a `list`) before using `choice` in python3.

Comment: Actually, you _can't_ call it on the key view, or on the dict itself. `choice` requires a _sequence_, not just an iterable.

Comment: The simplest solution (which is fine for a dict this small) is `choice(tuple(vocabulary))`.

Comment: @abarnert in python 3, right. It's true that the choice function requires an indexed thing, I'll update to reflect that.

Comment: It requires a sequence in Python 2 as well, it just doesn't _check_ it, so if you do, say, `choice({0: "spam", 2: "eggs"})` it'll return `"spam"` half the time and `KeyError: 1` the other half the time. It doesn't actually _work_ unless your keys happen to be exactly `range(0, len(d))`. The only reason it works on `keys()` in 2.x is that `keys()` is already copying the keys into a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

vocabulary = {
  "to study (imperfective)": "изучать",
  "to begin (imperfective)": "начинать",
  "to begin (perfective)": "начать"
}
randomChoice = random.randint(0, len(vocabulary)-1)
randomChoice = list(vocabulary.keys())[randomChoice]
print randomChoice
print vocabulary[randomChoice]
```

prints:

> either: "to study (imperfective)" ,"to begin (imperfective)" or "to begin (perfective)"
>
> and: "изучать", "начинать" and "начать"